# How to change class when component is not equal to home than add class in header component in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a class in the header component when the route is not home. My code is:

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header />
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
  <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
  <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Header.js component code:

```
 <div className="all-category (here add-class when route is not equal to home)">
  <h3 className="cat-heading"><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>CATEGORIES</h3>
   <ul className="main-category">
    <li><a href="#">New Arrivals <i className="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul className="sub-category">
         <li><a href="#">accessories</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">best selling</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">top 100 offer</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can simply pass a prop or check the `pathname` in your components to determine whether you at home or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check  `props.history.location.pathname` in the header component
Also make sure to wrap the header component in `withRouter`
eg:

```js
const Header = props => {
  return <div className={props.history.location.pathname === '/anything' ? "YOUR_CLASS":""}>....</div>
}

export default withRouter(Header)
```